# Python: how to get consistent number of columns?

Tags: python, floating-point, special-characters, multiple-columns

I am creating my own chemical files to train a neural network. I want to have the following format :

C  -0.56253228  0.3335121   0.31736381   # atom and its 3 cartesian coordinates x, y, z.

I want that whenever I select x,y,z, it will correspond to reading columns 1,2 and 3.
But when I tried to do so, it doesn't work. Each atom (each row) has different shape!
How do use Python to remove all these extra columns '[' ; ']\n' ?
you can see the output of my code when I try to print x, y and z for different atoms...
P.S.: I want to keep the numbers as floats!

Thanks!

```
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.startswith ("NN") and filename.endswith(".xyz"):
  
        with open(filename) as f:
            for i, line in enumerate(f):

                if i > 2 and i < na: #na is number of atoms in the molecule

                    X = line.split(" ")
                    X= np.array(X)
                    print(X.shape)
                    X_no_empty_strings = []
                    X_no_newline = []
                    print (X)
                    for string in X:
                        if (string != ""):
                            X_no_empty_strings.append(string)
                    
                    print ("edit1 complete", X_no_empty_strings)
                    print ("edit1 column x", X_no_empty_strings[0])
                    print ("edit1 column y", X_no_empty_strings[1])
                    print ("edit1 column z", X_no_empty_strings[2])
```

the results look like this:

```
(5,)
['[-0.85038635' '' '0.68900173' '' '0.49302935]\n']
edit1 complete ['[-0.85038635', '0.68900173', '0.49302935]\n']
edit1 column x [-0.85038635
edit1 column y 0.68900173
edit1 column z 0.49302935]

(4,)
['[0.31778502' '1.5147795' '' '0.01285466]\n']
edit1 complete ['[0.31778502', '1.5147795', '0.01285466]\n']
edit1 column x [0.31778502
edit1 column y 1.5147795
edit1 column z 0.01285466]

(6,)
['[' '0.88690126' '' '0.70133678' '-1.0899707' ']\n']
edit1 complete ['[', '0.88690126', '0.70133678', '-1.0899707', ']\n']
edit1 column x [
edit1 column y 0.88690126
edit1 column z 0.70133678
(3,)
['[-1.47555639' '-0.21571745' '-0.60427323]\n']
edit1 complete ['[-1.47555639', '-0.21571745', '-0.60427323]\n']
edit1 column x [-1.47555639
edit1 column y -0.21571745
edit1 column z -0.60427323]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output it seems that the entries in your .xyz files contain coordinates in square brakes. Could you please post couple lines, it would make it simpler to test the code. If that is not the case, try changing this:

```
X = line.split(" ")
X = np.array(X)
```

to this:

```
X = line.strip().split()
X[0] = X[0][1:] # strip opening braket
X[-1] = X[-1][:-1] # strip closing braket
X = np.array(X, dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: my input files do have brackets. each line looks like: [ 0.88690126  0.70133678 -1.0899707 ]
[-1.47555639 -0.21571745 -0.60427323]
[1.55769585 0.69655976 0.26742602]
[ 1.2332396  -0.58474004  1.09017548]
[-1.4068548  -1.41459723  0.31636935]
[ 0.23779748 -1.29611288 -1.69273918]

Comment: I am sorry I don't know how to comment in this section with formatted code ...

Comment: Try using the code I have posted, it should help with brackets. Hope you do know how to accept answers though :)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was really useful for formatting! It doesn't work the conversion back to float, "ValueError: could not convert string to float: " but I will try to find the solution to that.

Comment: It must be some non-digit or sign symbols that are left in your input file lines. I cannot say for sure without a sample of input. Glad that formatting got a bit simpler with my reply.

Comment: Now I know why i am not able to share code as an edit from my original question, is a newbies thing :P , you need certain reputation to be able to do that.

Comment: I guess I can help a little you with that as likes boost your reputation, accepting answer also boost it a bit.